# How to get a refresh Token with Google OAuth2 javascript?

Tags: javascript, refresh, token, google-oauth

I don't know how to request an refresh token with Javascript for Google APIs.

I've tried these: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

But I don't know how to get the response.

Comment: Did you try any code? Or you are unsure of how OAuth operates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't request a refresh token from Javascript (at least not in a browser). The URL you posted is describing the web server flow, which is the only place you can get a refresh token.

Comment: Are you sure of this because the api doc lists acesstype as one of the parameters that can be passed - https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference#sign-in_button_attributes

Comment: you're right. however if you read on you will see "If using the server-side sign-in flow and you want to get a refresh token". Delivering a refresh token to a javascript client would blow a huge hole in the oauth security model.